# Issue installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu on my AMD A9 acer Laptop and after installing via a USB boot drive I have ran into a command prompt screen from the bios saying **"tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request for resource [mem oxdfbb6000-0xdfbb9fff]
kfd kfd: amdgpu: STONEY  not supported in kfd"**
I have found some things on this online but nothing that has helped me so far I have tried restarting my entire download, restarting from bios, disabling security, uninstalling and Force-Installing firmware and no luck. Any help would be generously accepted.

Comment: You've provided us with few specifics, esp. what Ubuntu product, what release & for some which have different ISO choices which ISO you are attempting to use. Did you select an appropriate architecture/ISO for your hardware? validate ISO prior to write to media? validate write to media etc?